# Sinatra: How limit download file speed

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is it possible using sinatra limit the speed of downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it in configuration of web server you using like nginx, [here](https://github.com/bigplum/Nginx-limit-traffic-rate-module) is module for this.